# Angular 8: global variable this.chats is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a model called **Chat**, and it is like this:

```
export class Chat {
chatId?: number;
chatUser1?: string;
chatUser2?: string;
chatStatus?: string;
created_at?: any;
updated_at?: any;
deleted_at?: any;
```

}

In the commponent I want tho find the **chatUser2** with an specific value, so, I declared an array called **chats** for that model, like this.

```
chats:Chat[];
```

and then, I got this function:

```
getChats(): void { 
this.loadingChats = true;

this.chatService.getChats().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  this.chats = data;
});

this.toCall=true;
this.toAnswer=false;
this.toHangUp=false;
var status="true";

var chatUser2 = [];
var chatStatus = [];
var chatChannel = [];

chatUser2 = this.chats.map((v)=>v.chatUser2);
chatStatus = this.chats.map((v)=>v.chatStatus);
chatChannel = this.chats.map((v)=>v.chatId.toString());

var size = chatUser2.length;



for(var i=0; i<size ; i++) 
{
  console.log(i.toString());
  if(chatUser2[i] === this.userName && chatStatus[i]===status) 
  {
    this.toAnswer=true; 
    this.toCall=false;
    this.toHangUp=false;
    this.channel=chatChannel[i]; 
    console.log("break");
    break;
  }
}
```

But the console shows this error **ERROR TypeError: "this.chats is undefined"** in :

```
chatUser2 = this.chats.map((v)=>v.chatUser2);
```

**Thanks a lot.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this `chatService.getChats()` (observable) is an async operation you need to wait until it complete, one way to solve this by using async/await

```js
async getChats() : Promise<void> { 
this.loadingChats = true;

this.chats = await this.chatService.getChats().toPromise();

this.toCall=true;
this.toAnswer=false;
this.toHangUp=false;

var status="true";
var chatUser2 = [];
var chatStatus = [];
var chatChannel = [];

chatUser2 = this.chats.map((v)=>v.chatUser2);
chatStatus = this.chats.map((v)=>v.chatStatus);
chatChannel = this.chats.map((v)=>v.chatId.toString());

var size = chatUser2.length;

for(var i=0; i<size ; i++) 
{
  console.log(i.toString());
  if(chatUser2[i] === this.userName && chatStatus[i]===status) 
  {
    this.toAnswer=true; 
    this.toCall=false;
    this.toHangUp=false;
    this.channel=chatChannel[i]; 
    console.log("break");
    break;
  }
}
```

another option is to move your code to the body of subscribe method

```js
getChats(): void { 
this.loadingChats = true;

this.chatService.getChats().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  this.chats = data;
  // .... 
});

}
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for answer! but I tried it and I got this error **The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.**

Comment: I forget to update the  method return type from `:void` to `: Promise<void>`

Comment: Thanks, the return type worked, but **ERROR TypeError: "this.chats is undefined"** continues.

Comment: I just read the updated answer. Moving the code to the body of subscribe method worked! Thans a lot Sir!!